# DotNetZip password error special characters

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

When I open the zip file with the following code (specifying the password), I can get the files inside.

If I open the archive using IZArc and set the password there, it tells me that the password is invalid.

What can be the reason for this issue?

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
            zip.Password = "ïÁ×éÖËØ";
            zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.PkzipWeak;

            var fullTaxFormFilePath = @"C:\DETALHE.txt";
            zip.AddFile(fullTaxFormFilePath, "");

            zip.Save(@"C:\DETALHEZIP.zip");
 }
```

Comment: First guess would be that the input textbox for WinRar doesn't support those characters.

Comment: How are you using WinRAR? From the command line or the GUI? Are you *sure* WinRar supports Unicode characters in the password? These aren't special characters, just Unicode

Comment: Does your code example work?

Comment: Yes, but i can't open this file in other programmer, because this password

Comment: try using a simpler password "aaaaa" and see if the problem is with the characters

Comment: I see, but I can't use a simple password

Comment: in company I have been working they have a system with this pattern..and i have to follow it

Comment: The suggestion is for testing, not live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is internally DotNetZip uses the [IBM437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) code page and not unicode when converting the password (look for StringToByteArray in the source [here](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Zip/Shared.cs)). The code page was originally the one in the IBM PC so it's possible that's why it was chosen by PkZip. Because DotNetZip uses this code page it means that some of those characters are mapped in strange ways due to fallback. For example your password maps to the following (ignore the ?, that's just cause those aren't real chars):

ï - 0x8b - ?, Á - 0x41 - A, × - 0x78 - x, é - 0x82 - ?, Ö - 0x99 - ?, Ë - 0x45 - E, Ø - 0x4f - O.

Unless IZArc uses the exact same fallback behaviour then you'll not be able decrypt the file. Unfortunately IZArc seems to be closed source so I can't verify what it uses.

Comment: Do you know other way I can do it?

Comment: I'd say probably not in a repeatable way between different zip decoders. Looking at the specs (https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/APPNOTE/APPNOTE-6.3.3.TXT) in section 6.0 it doesn't even state what text encoding to use for update_keys. You could modify DotNetZip to not use the 437 code page and just map characters directly but there's no guarantee that's what applications like IZArc are doing.